# iOS: UITableView Selective Touches

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UITableView` that has certain cells that are a different height. I was hoping to have a way, without adding a button to each cell, to not receive responses to didSelectedRowAtIndexPath, if the touches in the cell are below a certain point.

As an example, say I have two cells, one that has a height of 100 and another with a height of 150. Is there a way to not receive responses to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` for touches below 100, but still receive the touch input on the cell?

I thought of overriding the touches methods in the cell and returning the point of contact in a delegate to the controller/table and using that input to determine whether or not I will ignore the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` response, but I'm worried about the highlighting and other calls and whether it may not be fast enough to block those as well. It just seems really iffy to me.

Answer (score 3):

I think without subclassing the cell, it isn't possible.

My suggestion would be to do this:

1. Create a Subclass of the cells
2. Add an extra boolean iVar to the cells, like didTapOutside
3. Set the boolean to True or False, based ont he Y position tap in the `touchesBegan` method
4. In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` read the didTapOutside boolean variable and according to it's setting do your actions

Example follows:

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    BOOL didTapOutside;
}
@property (atomic, readwrite) BOOL didTapOutside;
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation MyCustomCell

@synthesize didTapOutside;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    didTapOutside =  (location.y>100);

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: So, basically its as I thought that I would have to override the touches methods and have the method ignore the results based on the boolean. Its much lighter to use a delegate (adapting to a protocol), versus a boolean property on the cell, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom `UITableViewCell` for example:

```
CustomCell *cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:rect reuseIdentifier:identifier];
```

You could override the touchesBegan method in the CustomCell and do something like the following to get the position of the touch:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [aTouch locationInView:self];
    // point.x and point.y have the coordinates of the touch

    // based on where the touch is... your custom code

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Bej, but I had already mentioned this possibility in my question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, i see that now.  If you're concerned about the order of calls i suppose you could implement your own TableView touch controls.  Disable touches and add your own gesture recognizer to a tableview controller.  Then choose which touches to receive.  I'm not sure this is any less "iffy."

Comment: Yeah. I had thought about that, but then I realized I was lazy, so I think I'll just have to deal with iffy. They were great suggestions, though. I may leave this open for a bit in case someone else can come up with something, though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i read the question wrong at first. There is no easy solution for this.

If you do not want to use a sub class, the only thing you can do is add a transparent view or button on the area you want to detect touch and create an event on that instead of using the table view cell methods.

Comment: I'm fine with subclassing (especially since my cell is already subclassed), but the only solution with subclassing is very iffy, especially since its basically racing other threads to execute code.

Comment: Well, I can't say for certain, but at what point does the delegate get called between the table and cell? I get that the touches methods SHOULD be first, but without more information, there's no way to actually know, is there?

Comment: If they all use the action you are adding you can ignore the didSelectRowAtIndexPath all together. There is no race because we are only looking for the action you are adding to the cell on your own.

Comment: @miex I'm actually looking for my own action when someone selects a button, but I still need the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` call, otherwise I would just ignore the response anyways. But thank you for the suggestions.